# Which one is correct: “if you so wish” or “if you wish so”?

Tags: word-order

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Which one is correct: “if you so wish” or “if you wish so”?
Is there a rule for this?

Answer (score 1):

The normal phrase is *If you so wish*, but you should regard this as an idiom, because it has an archaic structure.

The only other phrase I can think of that uses *so* before the verb with that meaning is *It was/will be so agreed*.

In any other case, to use "so" in the sense of "what was stated before", put it after the verb: *I think so*. *He did so*.

Having said that, *If you wish so* is not idiomatic, and I'm not sure why. I think it may be that *so* (with that meaning) can only follow certain verbs: *be*, *do*, *think*, *believe*, *say*. But I'm not certain about that explanation.

With other verbs, you can sometimes use *it/them so* as the object: (eg *Make it so!*), and that is how you would manage it in this case: *If you wish it so* is pretty formal, but not unidiomatic.

Comment: @Jaime: are there? I couldn't think of another. _So_ in that position is usually an intensifier, not a resumptive pronoun.

Comment: To be clear, there are plenty of other closely related phrases that can use that 'so' before the verb structure (they're not always pretty):
- "The service shall be provided immediately upon the company so demanding" (in a contract)
- "The person so sentenced must to attend at the location of the community service so imposed at the date and time that the police so stipulate." (in a judicial decision)
- Q "Will you be at the clifftop at sunset?" A "If you so desire." (in a fantasy story)

Comment: Sorry about deleting the first comment. I got distracted by another issue and had to start again.

Comment: The first of those is _so_ before a participle, not a finite verb, and I'll allow it has more currency in that context. I don't think you'd find _the company so demands_. The second one, I'll give you (though I was distracted by the first two "so's" in the sentence which have a different meaning).

Comment: The meanings are all closely related.

Comment: There do appear to be two closely related meanings of the 'so' so placed:  " ... in that manner" (with verbs of doing) or " ... it to be that way/in that manner" (with verbs of desiring/wishing/requiring/demanding/imposing). The two senses are not all that different really.

Comment: "If the company so demands" produced 1220 items in a Google search, most of which were references to contracts. Not many items, admittedly, but the expression does seem to appear in a number of English-language contracts.

Answer (score 0):

The correct option is "If you so wish", which can be interpreted as "If you wish it to be so".

"If you wish it so" is another possibility; or even "If you wish", but "If you wish so" would just be incomprehensible, I'm afraid.

It's not an idiomatic expression, though ... nor should its structure be considered archaic.

It does, however, sound a little formal, and perhaps a little quaint.